# Mobile redirect with full link to go to full site

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to finally find a solution for this with maybe some steps.  i have the below javascript to point to a mobile site. and this works well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)|(Windows Phone)|(BlackBerry)/i))) {
    document.location = "http://www.c5mobile.com/drglenn/index.html";
}
(function(a,b) {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        return; // skip redirect
    }
    if (location.search.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        document.cookie = 'fullsite=true; path=/;'
        return; // skip redirect
    } 
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://www.c5mobile.com/drglenn/index.html')
</script>
```

But on the mobile site i would like to go to the full site , but it keeps looping.  this is the link im using below.

```
<a href="http://drdibart.com?fullsite=true">Full site</a>
```

anyone have any thoughts on why it keeps looping back to the mobile site?

Comment: did you debug this with logging ? does it go into the if statement where you seem to search for the query-param ?

Comment: well you need a gate keeper to know that if fullsite=true, then don't redirect to mobile

Comment: No clue what that means, any extra info? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding this will work no?

```
if ( (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)|(Windows Phone)|(BlackBerry)/i)) && location.search.indexOf('fullsite') < 0 ) {
    document.location = "http://www.c5mobile.com/drglenn/index.html";
}
```

I only added

```
&& location.search.indexOf('fullsite') < 0
```

as the second condition to the if statement. Currently the redirect will happen in the fist if statement of your script

Comment: Tried that, didnt seem to redirect.  just lopped agian, are you getting the same thing?

Comment: Try removing that function and find out exactly which line of js is causing the issue

Comment: so remove? if ( (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)|(Windows Phone)|(BlackBerry)/i)) && location.search.indexOf('fullsite') < 0 ) {
    document.location = "http://www.c5mobile.com/drglenn/index.html";
}

Comment: no remove the function function(a,b), it is the only function that's there

Comment: ok so the only left was <script type="text/javascript">
if ( (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)|(Windows Phone)|(BlackBerry)/i)) && location.search.indexOf('fullsite') < 0 ) {
    document.location = "http://www.c5mobile.com/drglenn/index.html";
}

</script> and its just keeps looping

Comment: I went to drdibart.com?fullsite=true and it does not redirect me on Ios simulator. I also did not find a link to full site on the mobile site.

Comment: the menu option is called "Visit our regular site"

Comment: excellent seemed to work, im on a windows phone and i guess it was cached.

Comment: Tried on IOS simulator and Samsung android s3, both works. Are you sure you refreshed your page and typed the link correctly? drdibart.com?fullsite=true make sure you have no typos. Appreciated it if you mark this answer as correct